# ¿Puedo hacer un campo con un array de objetos [Object] en un Schema de mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Necesito que mi Schema pueda recibir un array con esta estructura:

```
const arrayAnswers: [
    {description: 'String', isCorrect: true},
    {description: 'String', isCorrect: false},
    {description: 'String', isCorrect: false}
]
```

Este es el esquema que escribo:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const fields = {
  answers: [Object]
}

const question = new Schema(Object.assign(fields), {timestamps: true});

module.exports = {
  Model: mongoose.model('question', question),
  fields
};
```

¿El esquema para ese campo puede ser así o hay algún problema con el `[Object]`?

He leído sobre `Schema.Types.Mixed` y sobre subdocumentos, pero no sabría como hacer el subdocumento. Y según, el Mixed hace que se pierda la habilidad de autodetectar y guardar cambios, entonces no sé que repercusiones puede tener exactamente con lo que hago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por supuesto que puedes hacerlo. Si la estructura del objeto que vas a almacenar en tu campo `answers` es fija, entonces puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  const answers: [{
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: 'Description field is required'
    },
    isCorrect: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: 'isCorrect field is required'
    }
  }]
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = {
  Model: mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema)
}
```

Lo que hemos hecho es  definir el campo `answers` como tipo `array` y dentro hemos establecido la estructura del tipo de documento que contendra. He usado restricciones `required` sobre los campos del documento, aunque puedes no necesitarlas, eso dependerá de tu lógica.

Hacerlo de la forma que intentas (según lo que expones en tu pregunta) haría que el tipo de dato almacenado en el campo `answers` fuese de tipo `Mixed` por defecto.

Puedes leer más sobre el tipo `Array` de Mongoose en la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu duda.